# how to customize sitefinity's default mvc form widget's thank you message as html?

Tags: sitefinity, sitefinity-10

I have created a test form and displayed using sitefinity's default mvc form widget and when submitting the form it displays thank you message(directly as text) without any html. I want to add some html with it so that i can style it as per my liking.[image: Currently it is displayed as the image shows]

Answer (score 1):

Change the form on the page to use UseAjaxSubmit from the widget designer model. After this go to "\ResourcePackages\Bootstrap\MVC\Views\Form\Index.cshtml" and find this piece of code.

```html
    if (Model.UseAjaxSubmit)
    {

            <h3 data-sf-role="success-message" style="display: none;">
                @Model.SuccessMessage
                <div>my customized message</div>
            </h3>
```

You can change the rendering directly in the default template but I would recommend you to create a new template for the widget and keep the default one.

Answer (score 0):

The [Sitefinity Knowledgebase](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/modifying-the-form-responses-thank-you-message) contains workarounds to override this when using AjaxSubmit or not.

> If using AjaxSubmit is **not enabled**:
>
> 1. Create a new file under the Form folder (again, ResourcePackages > Bootstrap > MVC > Views > Form) with the following name: "Form.SubmitResultView.cshtml"
> 2. Use the following to display the styled text:
>
> `@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.SubmitMessage))`

I ended up having to add my Form.SubmitResultView.cshtml under Mvc > Views > Forms and used the following markup as I needed a consistent wrapper div:

```
<div class="some-class">
    @ViewBag.SubmitMessage
</div>
```